# How do I Get the SharePoint Online Build Version?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, modern-experience, build-version

Can someone help me to recall how to get SharePoint Online build version? In many cases, some SPO glitches/bugs can only be replicated in some tenants, but not in others. Is there some URL we can open in the browser that returns SPO build version? I think, there was a way, but after searching for 15 minutes I could not find it.

Any suggestions are really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use **Service cnf file**. To see build version, Open your default SharePoint site in browser `https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/_vti_pvt/service.cnf`

[image]

You can find other ways in below reference.

**Reference**: [How to Check SharePoint Online Version?](https://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-check-sharepoint-online-version/)

Comment: thank you, Ganesh!

Answer (score 1):

Note that service.cnf isn't a reliable way to determine "build". This number does not get updated with every deployment of a fix and/or feature and many SPO services are microservices outside of the farm (i.e. co-authoring isn't a SharePoint service and storage is in Azure Blobs, not the content database).

To troubleshoot, you'd likely need Microsoft support cases.